# PyQt: Adding tabs

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I am trying to add tabs to my program but it isn't working so far; the tabs show up but over the menubar and I am not sure why. Here is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
import os
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Notepad(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Notepad, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        newAction = QtGui.QAction('New', self)
        newAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
        newAction.setStatusTip('Create new file')
        newAction.triggered.connect(self.newFile)

        saveAction = QtGui.QAction('Save', self)
        saveAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')
        saveAction.setStatusTip('Save current file')
        saveAction.triggered.connect(self.saveFile)

        openAction = QtGui.QAction('Open', self)
        openAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openAction.setStatusTip('Open a file')
        openAction.triggered.connect(self.openFile)

        closeAction = QtGui.QAction('Close', self)
        closeAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        closeAction.setStatusTip('Close Notepad')
        closeAction.triggered.connect(self.close)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(newAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(saveAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(openAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(closeAction)

        tab_widget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)     # add tab
        tab1 = QtGui.QWidget()
        tab_widget.addTab(tab1, "Main") 

        self.text = QtGui.QTextEdit(tab_widget)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.text)

        self.setGeometry(300,300,300,300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Notepad')
        self.show()

    def newFile(self):
        self.text.clear()

    def saveFile(self):
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', os.getenv('HOME'))
        f = open(filename, 'w')
        filedata = self.text.toPlainText()
        f.write(filedata)
        f.close()


    def openFile(self):
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', os.getenv('HOME'))
        f = open(filename, 'r')
        filedata = f.read()
        self.text.setText(filedata)
        f.close()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    notepad = Notepad()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am trying to get it so the tab contains the text box. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create a text widget in the `initUI`, but create it in the `newFile` and `openFile` methods and then add it to the `tab_widget` (also save the reference to the `tab_wiget` in `initUI` so you can access it later). For example:

```
def openFile(self):
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', os.getenv('HOME'))[0]
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        filedata = f.read()
        text_widget = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.tab_widget)
        text_widget.setText(filedata)
        self.tab_widget.addTab(text_widget, os.path.basename(filename))
```

Comment: It isn't working for me yet; I tried doing it to newFile, but part of the tab box, it looks like, is covering the menu bar still. [Here](http://pastebin.com/JxCsu31P) is my code.

Comment: You are missing `self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)` after line 41.

Comment: Ok, it is almost working now, but for some reason the text area doesn't fill the whole tab area. How would I do that? [Here](http://pastebin.com/26PvMKsK) is my current code.

Comment: Don't create a widget, just add the text directly to the tab_widget. Replace the code in `newFile` with: `text = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.tab_widget); self.tab_widget.addTab(text, "Untitled.asm")`